# React CSSTransition not animating

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions, reactcsstransitiongroup

I want to animate a box (fade-in, fade-out) in my web app. I am using [react-transition-group](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition) for this. But somehow, the animation is not working. Code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

import './styles.css';

class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false,
  };

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isOpen: !prevState.isOpen,
    }));
  };
  render() {
    const modalStyles = {
      overlay: {
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      },
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>
          Open Modal
        </button>
        <CSSTransition
          in={this.state.isOpen}
          timeout={300}
          classNames="dialog"
        >
          <Modal
            isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
            style={modalStyles}
          >
            <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>
              Close Modal
            </button>
            <div>Hello World</div>
          </Modal>
        </CSSTransition>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.dialog-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms linear;
}
.dialog-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.dialog-exit {
  opacity: 0;
}
.dialog-exit-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/csstransition-component-z1y2r) is the working code. Click on "Open Modal" to open the modal and then click on "Toggle Box" to open/close the box which I want to animate.

EDIT: I am actually trying to get the box slide-in and slide-out when toggled. Here is

the updated CSS:

```
.dialog-enter {
  left: 100%;
  transition: left 1500ms;
 }
.dialog-enter-active {
  left: 0;
}
.dialog-exit {
  left: 0;
  transition: left 1500ms;
}
.dialog-exit-active {
  left: 100%;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50vh;
  background: blue;
```

Updated code [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/csstransition-component-9u39g)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to trust the mount/unmount to the CSSTransition entirely.

```
  <CSSTransition
    in={this.state.boxVisible}
    timeout={1500}
    classNames="dialog"
    unmountOnExit
  >
    <div>
      <div className="box">Box</div>
    </div>
  </CSSTransition>
```

See here: https://codesandbox.io/s/csstransition-component-9obbb

**UPDATE:**
If you want to move an element with the left css property as you asked in the comment. You must add the position: realative style to it as well.

```
.dialog-enter {
  left: 100%;
  transition: left 1500ms;
  position: relative;
}
.dialog-enter-active {
  left: 0;
}
.dialog-exit {
  left: 0;
  transition: left 1500ms;
  position: relative;
}
.dialog-exit-active {
  left: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Even after adding `unmountOnExit`, it's only fading when opening, not while closing.

Comment: Because the opacity values were swapped in the css for the exit. See my example.

Comment: I updated the link, somehow the change was not saved.

Comment: This works in the code snippet. But why is `unmountOnExit` required? What's exactly happening? Somehow when applied to my app, there is no change..

Comment: It is my first try with CSSTransition, I just followed the example, and tried to make it work.

Comment: Ok. I tried sliding in the box (that was the real intention for my app). The animations don't work then. https://codesandbox.io/s/csstransition-component-9u39g

Comment: Try change the left to transform in css.

Comment: I have already added `transition: left`. That should have worked..

Comment: That's not a valid css. If you add position:realtive to your version, it works too. For each css like: .dialog-enter-active {
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
}

Comment: Can you update the code to get it working as intended?

Comment: It said I can't save more than 10 sandboxes without logging in. Sorry.

Comment: Just create a fork and then use that. Or open codeSandBox in another browser and manually copy the code into it.

Comment: I'm done with the programming today. I switched to phone from my laptop. I hope you manage to solve this one.

Comment: Will try. Will update the answer if I am able to resolve. Otherwise, if possible you may try tomorrow :)

Comment: I added the solution for your extra question at the end of my answer.